# Saving session attribute in a list

Tags: scala, gatling

I would like to save a session attribute in a list in my gatling simulation. What am trying to do is to get all the values of my JSON who are defined in a CV file and write it in a file. In my example below "test" is always equal to the value of the first jsonPath.

Here what I am doing:

```
val scn1 = scenario("[SCENARIO] GET")
.repeat(Nbproduct-1, "counter") (
  feed(csv(CSV).circular)
  .exec(http("get JSON")
    .get(url_1")
    .check(jsonPath("""$.${meta_ref}""").find.saveAs("test")))
    .pause(1) 
    .exec(session => {
            writer.write("\""+session("meta_cts").as[String]+"\":\"" +  session("test").as[String]+"\",\n")
       session
               }         
            )
```

I also tried this but it get the value of the counter...
                  .check(jsonPath("""$.${meta_ref}""").find.saveAs("""jdd_value("${counter}")""")))

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feeders are **shared** datasources, so first user will pop the first record, second user the second record, etc...

Then, it's not possible to define checks at runtime (depending on some entries in a file). All DSL components are builders that are only resolved once when the Simulation is loaded.